# Iterations in VBA - Comparable method in PHP

Tags: php, vba, excel

Using VBA code I found in a spreadsheet to adapt to an online PHP application. The code uses the bisection method in mathematics to find optimal value for a calculation required to price options.

```
Upper = estimate_upper
Lower = estimate_lower
UUpper = container

Start_Iteration:

 IterationCountE = 0.000000001
 While (Upper - Lower) > IterationCountE
   Mid = (Upper + Lower) / 2

   c1 = calculations1...
   c2 = calculations2...

   If (c2 - c1) > 0 Then
      Lower = Mid
   Else
      Upper = MId
   End If

Wend 'Ends the while loop

If (Round(Mid, 4) = Round(UUpper, 4)) Then
   Upper = 2 * UUpper
   UUpper = Upper
   GoTo Start_Iteration
End If

Function = Mid
```

For most part, I understand the mechanics of the iteration. My attempted PHP conversion is as follows:

```
$IterationCountE = 0.00000000001;

while ( ($Upper - $Lower) > $IterationCountE ) {

 $Mid = ($Upper + $Lower) / 2;

 $c1 = calculation1();
 $c2 = calculation2();

 if ( ($c2 - $c1) > 0 ) {
  $Lower = $Mid;
 } else {
  $Upper = $Mid;
 }

 if (round($Mid, 4) == round($UUpper, 4)) {
  $Upper = 2 * $UUpper;
  $UUpper = $Upper;
 }
}

return $Mid;
```

Is this the best way to approach an similar iteration in PHP? Would it be better to wrap the iteration in a function and refer back to it like in the VBA code?

I do not get the same value results when comparing the PHP output to the value from a macro.

Comment: No idea about the comparison between PHP and VBA. But just take into account that the `Round` function in VBA performs the "bankers rounding", while PHP does not. That may account for some (minute) differences between methods.